# How to transition between updated data of bar chart, in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to get an understanding of transitions in bar charts using D3. What I'm doing now is updating the chart between two different data sets. I have a transition included but it's starting from the the bottom of the axis rather than transitioning between the two. My goal is to have it transition between the two and later change the colors. I'm using this helpful [example](https://bl.ocks.org/syncopika/f1c9036b0deb058454f825238a95b6be) for understanding updated data (my snippet is not much different). Thank you for taking a look.

```
var bothData = [
{
    "year": "2014",
    "product": "Books & DVDs",
    "purchase": "0.5"
    },
    {
    "year": "2002",
    "product": "Books & DVDs",
    "purchase": "10"
    },
    {
    "year": "2014",
    "product": "Beer & Wine",
    "purchase": "7"
    },
    {
    "year": "2002",
    "product": "Beer & Wine",
    "purchase": "3"
    },
    {
    "year": "2014",
    "product": "Food",
    "purchase": "12"
    },
    {
    "year": "2002",
    "product": "Food",
    "purchase": "12"
    },
    {
    "year": "2014",
    "product": "Home Supplies",
    "purchase": "7"
    },
    {
    "year": "2002",
    "product": "Home Supplies",
    "purchase": "6"
    }
    ];

    var data2002 = [];
    var data2014 = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < bothData.length; i++){
        if(bothData[i]["year"] === "2002"){
            data2002.push(bothData[i]);
        }else{
            data2014.push(bothData[i]);
        }
    }

    function change(value){

        if(value === '2002'){
            update(data2002);
        }else if(value === '2014'){
            update(data2014);
        }
    }

    function update(data){
        xChart.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.product; }) );
        yChart.domain( [0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return + d.purchase; })] );

        var barWidth = width / data.length;

        var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
                .remove()
                .exit()
                .data(data, function(d){ return d.purchase; })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d, i){ return i * barWidth + 1 })
                .attr("y",500)
                .attr("height",0)
                .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
                .each(function(d){ 
                  if(d.year === "2014"){
                    d3.select(this)
                    .style('fill','#ea5454');
                  }else{
                    d3.select(this)
                    .style('fill','#4e97c4');
                  };
                });

        bars.transition()
          .duration(600)
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .attr('y', function(d){ return yChart(d.purchase); })
          .attr('height', function(d){ return height - yChart(d.purchase); });

        chart.select('.y').call(yAxis);


        chart.select('.xAxis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", ".15em")
                .attr("transform", function(d){
                    return "rotate(-65)";
                });

         }

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 95, left: 50};
    var width = 400;
    var height = 500;

    var chart = d3.select(".chart")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var xChart = d3.scaleBand()
                .range([0, width]);

    var yChart = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xChart);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yChart);


    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function(d){
            return "rotate(-65)";
                });

    chart.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-35," +  (height+margin.bottom)/2 + ") rotate(-90)")
        .text("Purchases");

    chart.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom - 5) + ")")
        .text("Products");

    update(data2002);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. The chart **is** updating. What's exactly your problem?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Sorry about confusion. I'm trying to have the bars rise from each other in transition. Right now, they're rising from the bottom of the chart when clicking the buttons. The final result bar chart on this site has an example of the transition I'm looking for. http://www.davesquared.net/2014/09/d3-update-a-bar-chart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea...you want to achieve object constancy as described [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/) by Mike Bostock.  The key for your constancy should be the "product" from your data (not "purchase").

In your `update` function, define `bars` like this:

```
var bars = chart.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data, function(d){ return d.product; })
```

then separate the `.enter`, `.exit` and `.transition` functions:

```
       bars.exit()
         .remove()
       bars.enter()
         ....
       bars.transition()
```

You have some strange stuff going on in your `.enter` function - like setting bar height to zero.  So I modified your .enter and .transition functions like this:

```
          bars.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", function(d, i){return i * barWidth + 1 })
            .attr("y",function(d){ return yChart(d.purchase); })
            .attr("height",function(d){ return height - yChart(d.purchase); })
            .attr("width", barWidth - 5)
            .attr('fill', function(d){ 
              if(d.year === "2014"){
                return'#ea5454'
              }else{
                return'#4e97c4'
              }

            })
    bars.transition()
      .duration(600)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .attr('y', function(d){ return yChart(d.purchase); })
      .attr('height', function(d){ return height - yChart(d.purchase); })
      .style('fill', function(d){
        if(d.year === "2014"){
          return '#ea5454'
        } else {
          return '#4e97c4'
        }
      })
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/genestd/asoLph2w/
Note the buttons on top to achieve the transition.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for pointing that out and sending Mike Bostock's description on constancy. I hadn't seen that before.